# C++ custom delete

Tags: c++

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class MyType
{
    public: int x;
}

MyType* object = new MyType();
delete object;
```

Is there a possible to check if object has specific value of x before deletion?
For example, if object.x is odd number, the object should not be free from memory after delete is called. In a few words to make a custom delete for this class where we can choose when the object can be free at operator delete call.

Comment: `void myDelete(MyType*& o) { if (o && o->x % 2 == 1) { delete o; o = nullptr;}  }`?

Comment: Like Jarod42 state you need to write such a function yourself before calling the actual delete function.

Comment: I think you should somehow overload `operator delete`

Comment: Irrelevant : why do you need such a thing? What is the design that needs that?

Comment: Doing something like this is HORRIBLE design. A call to `delete` should delete an object (or give it back to your memory management). Period. If you don't want to delete an object if it's in a particular state, then don't call delete on that object. The soution is simply `if(object->x % 2 != 1) delete object;`. Please don't write voodoo code.

Comment: Pretty bad idea to overload delete operator. You should do this check before calling delete. If operator delete is called than it should only delete ideally no other purpose should be allowed there.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan `operator delete` deallocates memory; the object that used to be there has already been destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What is the real issue you are trying to solve?

To begin with, this Q&A is a good lesson to the common scenario in C++ of:

- The language allowing you to do *something*, but just because you can doesn't mean you should.
- These scenarios are commonly run into when trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In this particular case, instead of trying to overload `operator delete` (solving the Y problem, to much confusion of the clients of `MyType`) you are likely looking for something entirely different (the X problem), say a resource manager that take responsibility of `MyType` resources w.r.t. if and when they should be deleted (or not), based on e.g. object traits (such as oddness of a data member). See e.g. [@Ayxan Haqverdili's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711692/4573247) for a minimal example.

---

#### A look at *theoretically* solving the misidentified Y problem

**Don't do this, ever, for this kind of use case.**

You *can* overload `operator delete` (as well as `operator delete[]`), by defining it as a static member function of the class for which you want to overload it (lookup precedence by lexical scope). As pointed out in the comments, whilst overloading the usual deallocation functions is legal, trying to conditionally  allow for it to be called more than once is not:

```
struct MyType final {
  int x;
  static void operator delete(void *p) {
    if (static_cast<MyType *>(p)->x % 2 == 1) {
      ::operator delete(p);
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  MyType *object = new MyType{42};
  delete object; // Not DEALLOCATED.
                 // Underlying object DESTRUCTED, however.
                 // Extremely confusing.
  ++(object->x);
  delete object; // UB: destructor for underlying object called twice.
}
```

as per [[expr.delete]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.delete#6) [**emphasis** mine]:

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value and the selected deallocation function (see below) **is not a destroying operator delete**, the delete-expression **will invoke the destructor (if any) for the object** or the elements of the array being deleted.

As a second attempt (emphasis: don't ever go down this road), we could avoid the destructor being called (only calling it conditionally) by overloading and abusing the (new as of C++20) class-specific destroying deallocation functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

struct MyType final {
  int x;
  static void operator delete(MyType *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
    if (p->x % 2 == 1) {
      p->~MyType();
      ::operator delete(p);
    }
  }
  ~MyType() {
      std::cout << "\ndtor";
  }
};

int main() {
  MyType *object = new MyType{42};
  delete object; // Neither deallocated nor underlying object destructed.
  ++(object->x);
  delete object; // Destructed and deallocated.
}
```

Afaict this program is well-formed, but it does abuse the new destroying delete overloads. Clang does emit a `-Wmismatched-new-delete` warning, which is typically a hint for UB, but it may be inaccurate here.

Anyway, this seems like a good place to stop the fruitless journey of addressing this particular Y problem.

Comment: It seems `g++` won't increase the value in `++(object->x);` while `clang++` does. [example @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/M5qWWGxo1). Also, `clang++` won't accept `new MyType(42)` but `new MyType{42}`

Comment: It is *still* UB. The destructor is called twice which is a big no-no.

Comment: @TedLyngmo accessing an object after its life time (i.e. after the destructor is called) is UB. Hence, GCC may ignore the `++`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes, I was just  looking for that in the standard. .) Here the destructor is only called once though - but calling `delete` on the same pointer twice also looks suspicious.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Interesting, I though, albeit horrible, the program above is well-formed. Afaict the destructor should only be called when we invoke the global scope operator delete? As linked by Ted GCC flags this as a leak, hinting the destructor is never called. On the other hand, compiler variance is a hint for UB. Thoughts?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the destructor is called twice. See output here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/joT6odoW5

Comment: @TedLyngmo A yes, MyType is an aggregate, so we need aggregate initialization, thanks.

Comment: @dfrib no, the destructor is called independently from `operator delete`. The destructor doesn't free the memory, `operator delete` does. Hence the memory leak. See output here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/joT6odoW5

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Thanks, I'll delete (no pun intended) or update the answer shortly.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I don't know why I spent more time on this horribleness ([yes I do](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/877/596/f66.jpg)), but I just ran into the destroying operator delete functions, which can be abused to conditionally not invoke the destructor of the underlying object. Introduced b [p0722r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0722r3.html).

Comment: @dfrib Good show! I didn't know such a thing existed. Obligatory [xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/356/).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Indeed, whilst I did not run over by a truck, I did forget to eat lunch x)

Comment: @TedLyngmo FYI: updated with some new curiosities, in case you also had an interest in this horribleness (see Ayxan xkcd) :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
if (object->x % 2 == 1)
    delete object;
```

Note that raw pointers should be used rarely and with a lot of care.